# How to executes NUnit tests in parallel with one agent in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nunit

We have 2 local computers that are used as agent. Both computers have one agent.
Those computers have at least 12 cores and we would like to run our tests in parallel, only on one computer. So my understanding is that there is no additionals agents needed, since I can execute Nunit directly in a parallel fashion.

In the documentation I found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/parallel-testing-vstest?view=azure-devops
The notion of running tests in parallels and on multiple agents seems linked.
I don't want to use multiple agents as it prevents using isolation.

Is there a way to avoid it? Use more than one core of one agent?

My current yml description:

```
  - task: VSTest@2
    timeoutInMinutes: 300
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: '*.Test*.dll'
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'
      codeCoverageEnabled: false
      platform: 'Any CPU'
      uiTests: false
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      rerunFailedTests: false
      pathtoCustomTestAdapters: 'Solution/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter.3.12.0/build/net35'
      minimumExpectedTests: 1000
      runInParallel: true
      runTestsInIsolation: true
      failOnMinTestsNotRun: true
      resultsFolder: 'testResults'
      runSettingsFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\azure-tests.runsettings'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable parallelism across agents you need to state that explicit on [job configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/parallel-testing-vstest?view=azure-devops#setting-up-jobs-for-parallel-testing-in-yaml-pipelines):

```yaml
jobs:
- job: ParallelTesting
  strategy:
    parallel: 2
```

If you didn't do that your tests run on one agent, which you want if I understood you.

Comment: I don't want parallelism accross agent, I just want on ONE agent to run tests in parallels(which NUnit allows)

Comment: I understood that. And since you didn't change strategy you will get only one agent to run your tests. And you have already `      runInParallel: true` set on VSTest task so it seems that you have all what you need. Can you explain where the problem is? Probably I missed sth, but for me it looks that you have everything covered.

Comment: I've not the impression that anything is runned in parallel, the CPU is only used 4-5%, lots of memory available and tests takes forever

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside parallelism across agents, NUnit itself has two kinds of parallelism: between separate processes and within one process.

The first kind is unfortunately what **NUnit** also calls "agents" but has nothing to do with the agents your question is talking about. In any case, that's not available to you when running tests through the NUnit 3 VS adapter because it relies on the host to handle processes rather than creating one itself.

This leaves the second kind of NUnit parallelism: use of multiple threads within the test process. This is mainly controlled by your use of attributes in the test assembly.

[`[Parallelizable]`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/parallelizable.html) tells NUnit that it is safe to run a particular test in parallel with others. If you are not using it already, it takes a fair bit of work to determine which tests may run in parallel within the same process.

You can use [`LevelOfParallelismAttribute`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/levelofparallelism.html) on the assembly to specify the number of parallel threads to be used or let it default to the number of cores available.

You'll have to determine for yourself whether it's worth the effort to parallelize your tests in this way as opposed to configuring multiple agents on each machine.

Another alternative would be to run using NUnit 3 Console rather than the vstest runner. In that case, each test assembly defaults to running in a separate process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it required to use the `Parallelizable` attribute if the `LevelOfParallelismAttribute` is used? We have 30 assemblies of tests and we would like each of them(In the limit of available core) to be run in parallel, but not run in parallel accross the same assembly, is that possible?

Comment: @J4N Your comment indicates you __do not__ want NUnit's parallel support within the test assembly, so you don't need - and shouldn't use - either attribute. Instead, you want what each test assembly to run separately, in parallel with the others. NUnit 3 console supports doing this but the NUnit 3 adapter, which is used under vstest, does not. This is __by design__ because it's assumed that the host provide separate agents for each process if that's what is needed.

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong, but we only have one agent per computer. So we cannot use the 12 core of our testing machine is quite useless? I tought that on Azure DevOps, the test adapter was the way to go. Is there some way of specifying that we want the tests to runs in parallel per assembly? Like the `ParallelizeAssemblies` of XUnit?

Comment: @J4N I answered from an NUnit perspective. I'm not an expert on Azure Devops so I didn't go there. However, it seems to me you either need to configure multiple agents on each machine or run your tests with the NUnit console runner. Somebody else will have to advise on that.

Comment: The problem is that using multiple agents seems to add a lot of overhead(actually if I keep one computer but ask VSTests to splits tests into multiples agents, my tests take 2h instead of 1h15). Plus, it require to have pay extra agents, plus it means that some other tasks than tests will be able to execute in parallel on this machine. It has a lot of downside. It's a shame that we cannot use the efficient NUnit to parallelize and burn those cores. Do you think it would be possible to add an option to make the test adapter running in parallel?